# In an acyclic graph (E,V), find paths which sum up to 0

Tags: algorithm

Acyclic graph(tree) (E,V) given. Find all paths (path is a sequence of neighbouring nodes), where nodes on the path sum to 0.

Brute force approach would be to generate all pairs of nodes, for each pair check if the nodes' values sum to 0. This takes O(N^3) time and O(N) space complexity. Please suggest faster solution.

Comment: By "nodes" do you mean that each node has a key and a path sums the keys? Or does the weight reside on the arcs?

Comment: Nodes do have keys, and we're summing keys

Comment: Find any, some, or all paths?

Comment: Does it have to start at the root?

Comment: @sdasdadas The path does not have to start at the root

Comment: One more question - node weights are all positive?

Comment: @sdasdadas No, otherwise it is too easy. :)

Comment: @MichalWegorek Where do you have this problem from?

Comment: Are the values floating point numbers or integers?  If integers, how does the maximum value for the integer compare to n?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz the same question from me :) Are you thinking of a DP solution?

Comment: @Peter de Rivaz The values are integers. The problem comes from my mind, I wanted to discuss different approaches, feel free to provide a solution with values in a range [-n, n]

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in O(n^2) time by running a depth first search for each choice of start node.

The depth first search computes the distance for each node from the root start node.  A path is found whenever the distance is 0.

There are n nodes, and each DFS takes O(n) so the total running time is O(n^2).

It is hard to do much better in general because if all your nodes have weight 0, then you need to output O(n^2) answers.

### Python code

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(0,1)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
W=[1,0,-1,-1]

def dfs(G,n,dist,parent):
    """Depth first search and yield nodes where sum is 0."""
    dist += W[n]
    if dist==0:
        yield n
    for n2 in G[n]:
        if n2!=parent:
            for e in dfs(G,n2,dist,n):
                yield e

for start in G:
    for n in dfs(G,start,0,None):
        print start,n
```

Note that this returns 2 entries for each path 0->2 and 2->0, and also returns paths 1->1 if a node has zero weight.

You can remove these extra cases by only outputting an answer if start < n.

### Counting solutions

If you just want to know the number of solutions you can do this in O(nlogn) and O(n) space by splitting the tree into smaller pieces.

1. Choose a node in the centre of the graph ( O(n) to find it, although I suspect that picking a random node will work well in practice in the same way as quicksort works well)
2. Find all paths of zero weight that include this node by running a DFS for each neighbour and storing the distances in a dictionary mapping distance to count of nodes with that distance.  Comparing the dictionaries allows us to find paths of zero weight.  O(n)
3. Now repeat this algorithm for the subgraphs rooted at each child

For a binary tree we will have 2 subgraphs of size at most n/2, so the second stage will take about the same number of operations, and similarly each stage takes O(n) until the subgraphs contain a single node.  There will be O(logn) stages, so overall the complexity is O(nlogn).

For a non-binary tree there are more subgraphs, but they are also smaller, so each stage will take O(n) as before, but we should bottom out faster, so non-binary trees should also be O(nlogn).  (Also doing step2 is slightly more complicated but can still be done in O(n))

Comment: Let's say we don't need to output the paths, we need to count them. Is O(n^2) still low boundary?

Comment: This is assumed to be an acyclic graph, so pairs of paths like 0->2 and 2->0 can't happen.

Comment: @Michal I've added a note explaining how to count solutions in O(nlogn).  This method does not depend on the weights being small integers.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz if the graph is a DAG and not a tree, then your dfs doesn't run in O(n). Notice that you're not marking vertices as visited during the procedure and of course, you're not counting edges in the complexity

Comment: @pkacprzak I agree, it will have higher complexity for a general DAG.  I just addressed the case of a tree because the question mentioned that the graph was a tree.

Answer (score 1):

An O(n) solution using the following code in Python. As it is a tree, we don't need to check for visited nodes.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, id, weight):
        self.id = id
        self.weight = weight
        self.children = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Node {0}: {1}>'.format(self.id, self.weight)

class Solver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sums = defaultdict(list)
        self.path = []
        self.solutions = []

    def dfs(self, depth, node, acc):
        self.path.append(node)

        key = acc + node.weight
        for x in self.sums[key]:
            self.solutions.append(self.path[x+1:])

        self.sums[key].append(depth)
        for child in node.children:
            self.dfs(depth + 1, child, acc + node.weight)
        self.sums[key].pop()

        self.path.pop()

    def run(self, root):
        self.sums[0].append(-1)
        self.dfs(0, root, 0)
        return self.solutions

nodes = [
    Node('A', 5),
    Node('B', 1),
    Node('C', 2),
    Node('D', -3),
    Node('E', 1),
    Node('F', 2),
    Node('G', 0),
    Node('H', -8),
]
i = 0
while i < len(nodes) - 1:
    nodes[i].children.append(nodes[i+1])
    i += 1

s = Solver()
solutions = s.run(nodes[0])
for x in solutions:
    print x
```

The output is:

```
[<Node B: 1>, <Node C: 2>, <Node D: -3>]
[<Node C: 2>, <Node D: -3>, <Node E: 1>]
[<Node D: -3>, <Node E: 1>, <Node F: 2>]
[<Node D: -3>, <Node E: 1>, <Node F: 2>, <Node G: 0>]
[<Node G: 0>]
[<Node A: 5>, <Node B: 1>, <Node C: 2>, <Node D: -3>, <Node E: 1>, <Node F: 2>, <Node G: 0>, <Node H: -8>]
```

I'm assuming the dictionary methods to add, delete and access a key are O(1). If they aren't, you could use some hash to have it on average.

Explanation: in any path (..., n_i, ..., n_j, ...), we have that the sum of all weights from n_i to n_j is equal to `n_j.acc - n_(i-1).acc`. So we just have to find two nodes with the same accumulated sum. We use hash to find it in O(1).

Of course you can adapt it to only count the number of paths. You just have to sum the size of self.sums (and you can remove self.path).

Comment: It's O(n) in time and space.

Comment: Suppose the root has weight 2, and is connected to 2 children of weight -1 each.  I don't think this method will find the path.  (In general, I think it fails to find paths that go up and down in the tree but it does find paths that only go down the tree)

Comment: You are right, it doesn't find a path that goes up and down. I didn't suppose that it was a valid path. @Michal, is it a valid path? Any way, I'll think about it.

Comment: I can't code and test right now, but I guess just recording start time and end time of each node can solve the up and down issue. We just have to lookup twice (for acc and root.weight - acc) and check if nodes [start time, end time] overlaps. If yes, they are in the same branch and my approach works. If not, they are in different branches. I'll do the code later.

Comment: Is the following path valid? Notation: (node, child1, child2, ...). Tree: (4, -1, (-1, -1, -1)). It's a root with value three with two children. The first child is -1 and the second child is another tree with root -1 and two -1 children. If yes, it's not a path, but a walk, because you can't visit all these nodes without repeating at least one.